# Springdoc Data REST ignore overwrite Pageable parameters name

Tags: java, spring-data-rest, springdoc

In my application.properties, I have overwritten the name of the Pageable parameters:

```yaml
spring.data.web.pageable.page-parameter=offset
spring.data.web.pageable.size-parameter=limit
```

But when I go to the Swagger UI to check my Swagger documentation, the new name parameters are not used:

[image]

Here is the signature of my function:

```java
@PageableAsQueryParam
    @Operation(summary = "")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "",
                    content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = CustomPage.class))),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "", content = @Content)
    })
    @GetMapping(path = "/{version}/foo", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<CustomPage<ReducedAsset>> getAll(@ParameterObject Pageable pageable,
                                                           @Parameter(description = "Version from which to get the list")
                                                           @PathVariable String version)
```

How can I bind the new name to the documentation? And can I change the default description?

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest & less intrusive approach would be probably:

```java
package com.example.springdocdatarest;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.ParameterIn;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.ArraySchema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY,
     description = "Zero-based page index (0..N)",
     name = "offset", // !
     schema = @Schema(type = "integer", defaultValue = "0"))
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY,
     description = "The size of the page to be returned",
     name = "limit", // !
     schema = @Schema(type = "integer", defaultValue = "20"))
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY,
     description = "Sorting criteria in the format: property(,asc|desc). "
    + "Default sort order is ascending. " + "Multiple sort criteria are supported.",
     name = "sort",
     array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(type = "string")))
public @interface MyPageableAsQueryParam {

}
```

1. Copying from https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/blob/master/springdoc-openapi-common/src/main/java/org/springdoc/core/converters/models/PageableAsQueryParam.java
2. Replacing with the values we want. (also description;)

And using it:

```java
@com.example.springdocdatarest.MyPageableAsQueryParam
@Operation(summary = "") // ...
@GetMapping ...
```

Test (switching version and Pageable parameter (order;)):
[image: swagger-ui screenshot]

#### Note

There are also:

```properties
spring.data.rest.page-param-name=foo
spring.data.rest.limit-param-name=bar
spring.data.rest...
```

[spring-data-rest](/questions/tagged/spring-data-rest) properties for "these".

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!